# JQuery Get Number of Dynamically Created ID Fields on Form

Tags: jquery

Given this code:

```
<input type="text" name="pv1_qty" id="pv1_qty" size="1" value="0">
```

This form field has some associated checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="pv1_top0" name="pv1_top0" value="zero">
<input type="checkbox" id="pv1_top1" name="pv1_top1" value="one">
<input type="checkbox" id="pv1_top2" name="pv1_top2" value="two">
```

A user can click on a button to dynamically create another set of these form elements.  The names/ids of the new set will increment by 1:  `id="pv2_qty"`, `id="pv3_qty"`... etc.

Question. Using the text fields id or name attributes, how can I find out how many sets a user has created?  I'm not sure how to go about this.

`$('div[id^=pv]').count` I know this doesn't work, but maybe something like this?

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Given the limited info you've provided and the stipulation that it uses the "text field's id or name': `$('input[type=text][id^=pv]').length`  - I'd probably put all the controls in a wrapper div with a class then just count that, eg: `$(".inputwrapper").length`

Comment: Forget dynamically created incremental ids. It's an anti-pattern. Just given them all the same class and use `$('.yourClass').length`

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to just count the number of times the user clicks the button that generates new sets?

```
var count = 0

$("#buttonIdGenerateSets").on("click", function(){
    count++;
});
```

I might not be understanding the question tho

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you.

```
var arrNumber = new Array();
jQuery.each(jQuery('input[type=checkbox]'),function(){
    var group = jQuery(this).attr('id');
        group = group.split("_")[0];
    if ($.inArray(group, arrNumber) == -1) arrNumber.push(group);   
});
```